# Entity Framework - adding relationships when entities have not yet committed to the databse

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables: **[User]** and **[Group]** (PKs are called ID which is an IDENTITY coloumn).  The relationship is normalised in the database as a table called **[UserGroup]** with two columns: UserID and GroupID.

Up till now, the EF Model (using Database First) abstracted the **[UserGroup]** table and it did not appear as an explicit table.

I should point out now that both **[User]** and **[Group]** tables also contain a OrganisationID column and all users and groups (and their relationships) reside in specific Organisations)

I've now needed to add an OrganisationID field to **[UserGroup]** to improve performance in the database (so that **[UserGroup]** is clustered by OrganisationID).  As a result, after performing a Refresh from Database, **[UserGroup]** now appears as a distinct entity which has broken existing C# code that I use to assign users to groups.

Previously, if I had to create a group and assign it to user to it I would use:

```
user.Groups.Add(group);
```

Even if the group and user objects have only just been created and have yet to have a database key assigned to them, EF honoured the relationship by creating a **[UserGroup]** row with the newly generated user.ID and group.ID values upon SaveChanges().

Now that **[UserGroup]** exists as an explicit table in the EF model this code doesn't work (reason: an OrganisationID has to also be explicitly added) but I don't know how to create a **[UserGroup]** object and associate it with link it to newly created **[User]** and **[Group]** rows.

The closest I've got is this:

```
GroupUser gu = new GroupUser { GroupID = group.ID, OrganisationID = nOrganisationID, UserID = u.ID };
u.GroupUsers.Add( gu );
```

...but it's not going to work because the user.ID and group.ID are still 0.
Can anyone advise on this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add two navigation properties to `UserGroup`:

```
public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

and set them with the new group and user. EF will figure out the correct order to insert the data and set the primitive foreign key values just in time.

You can map this as

```
HasRequired(p => p.Group).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.GroupId);
```

in a `UserGroupMapping` class (`EntityTypeConfiguration<UserGroup>`).